# Behavior of array_search()

Tags: php, arrays, search

I am using function array_search to unset elements from a session array. Problems: if the key found is 0, returns false; if is selected the last element from the "list", it doesn't take it off from the browser's page but it is deleted from the array (works fine with the other elements); if i print out the $key it doesn't show the right key, but a value that keeps growing every time the result is a key that has been already "used". 
The first and second problems are of most interest to me. The code that unsets elements from array seem correct and logic to me so i need help again...

So I've set up a pagination that retrieves data from a DB table. Everything prints fine.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{   
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['ID']."</td><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>";
    if($row['stoc']==0) echo "Stoc 0</td></tr>";
    else echo "<a href=\"mousi.php?item=".$row['cod']."\">Add this</a></td></tr>";
}
```

Then if isset(GET['item']) ("Add this" button), build a session array and add to it the items selected one by one:

```
if(isset($_GET['item']))
{
    $cod=$_GET['item'];
    $item_q=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT name FROM mousi WHERE cod='$cod'");
    $item_f=mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_q);

    if(!in_array($item_f['name'],$_SESSION['prod'])) $_SESSION['prod'][]=$item_f['name'];
    foreach($_SESSION['produse'] as $elm)
        echo $elm."<a href='mousi.php?item=$cod&del=$elm'>Delete</a><br />";
}
```

And finally there is an if isset(GET['del']) condition writen before if isset(GET[item]) and this GET[del] unsets an element from the array $_SESSION['prod']:

```
if(isset($_GET['del']))
{
    $key=array_search($_GET['del'], $_SESSION['prod']); 
    if($key!==false) 
    {
        unset($_SESSION['prod'][$key]);
        echo $key." 'selected' key<br />"; //why would this grow like the last result is stored?
        print_r(array_values($_SESSION['prod'])); //just to see if the elements are actually deleted and they are, except the first one (key=0)
    }

    else echo "Key not found";  

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: do take note that the print_r array values result actually reindex keys

Comment: Please, give few clarifications. "if the key found is 0, returns false;" - who returns false? "it doesn't take it off from the browser's page" - I see that you print elements to browser from database, but unseting it from $_SESSION array. Why they should not be disaplayed?

Comment: @Ghost - i took that out and seems it works fine on key=0 now. To Yuriy Novikov - the function array_search returns false when it doesn't find the key, but in this case it was returning a "false false" when the result key was 0. Anyway i fixed that. The other matter: i want to display only the elements left in the array so if they are all deleted then print nothing... but the last element always remains and i don't want that...